# How do I use any of my system fonts in matplotlib GLOBALLY in the most straight-forward way possible?

Tags: python, matplotlib

First things first: Windows 10, python 3.8, matplotlib 3. (I've had the same problem with Anaconda python 3.7)

I've installed Helvetica from [this](https://www.fontmirror.com/helvetica) source in my C:\Windows\Fonts folder. I've tried running this script and get the following error:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams

rcParams['font.family'] = ['Helvetica Normal']

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

plt.show()
```

```
findfont: Font family ['Helvetica Normal'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.
```

I've tried Helvetica and Helvetica Standard before that. It works with Trebuchet, which, as far as I know, is only installed in my system fonts and not any of the matplotlib font folders.

I tried a lot of solutions, but I just don't know how to specify the font for matplotlib globally. I've tried every solution I found on github, stackoverflow etc. I've had this problem for over a year now but I can't find a suitable solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install the font in the system.
2. Locate the font file (in this case `C:\Windows\Fonts\Helvetica 400.ttf`)
3. Run

   ```
   fp = matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties(fname=r"C:\Windows\Fonts\Helvetica 400.ttf")
   print(fp.get_name())
   ```

   to get the name of the font printed. It would be `Helvetica` in this case.
4. Rebuild the font cache. This could be done by deleting the `fontlist-vXXX.json` (where `XXX = 310` for version 3.1.0) file from the matplotlib folder. Or by running `matplotlib.font_manager._rebuild()` via code.
5. Use the font name from step 3. in your code, e.g. `plt.rcParams['font.family'] = ['Helvetica']`

Comment: Thanks. Seems like one of the problems was that python won't acutally find the fonts in ```C:\Windows\Fonts\``` but in ```C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\```. I don't understand windows. Will the changes be permanent, or do I have to rerun the rebuild after every update or something?

Comment: If you install a new matplotlib version, the font cache will rebuild automatically. If you install a font in the meantime, recreate the font cache manually.